# New line in an output tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show a pyramid of stars in an output tag and I can't get a new line to appear after every row? The output tag has id "result" and i can get the error messages to work if a user doesnt insert a number.

```
function teken(){
    var resultaat =document.getElementById("result");
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = "";
    if(isNaN(getal.value)){
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = "Een GETAL als ingave aub";
    } else if(getal.value>10 || getal.value<2){
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = "Getal moet groter dan 2 en kleiner dan 10 zijn"
    } else {
        for(var i = 1; i<= getal.value; i++){
            for(var j = 1 ; j<=i;j++){
                resultaat.value += "*";
            }
            resultaat.innerHTML += "<br>"
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Potential typo: did you mean `resultaat.innerHTML += "*"` instead of `resultaat.value += "*"`?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, I think you just need `resultaat.innerHTML += "*"` instead of `.value`. Here's a trimmed down version of your code (with that edit) that works:

```js
var resultaat = document.getElementById("result");
var n = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        resultaat.innerHTML += "*";
    }
    resultaat.innerHTML += "<br>"
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I was using .value and the *s were still showing up the screen but without the new lines between them so I thought that wasnt the problem. But that fixed it! Thanks again